# Visual Studio 2015 connection to MS SQL 2008 Server

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2015

I've built an application in vb.net with Visual Studio 2015 which I need to update now. I need to update the Table Adapter through Dataset Designer but when I click Configure on the Query I get the error:

> Failed to open a connection to the database
>
> "The client was unable to establish a connection because of an error
>   during         connection initialization process before login. 
>   Possible causes include the following:  the client tried to connect to
>   an unsupported version of SQL Server;  the server was too busy to
>   accept new connections; or there was a resource limitation
>   (insufficient memory or maximum allowed connections) on the server.
>   (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other
>   end of the pipe.)"
>
> Check the connection and try again.

Previously this worked just fine. The application still works fine and connects to the MS SQL server using the same connection string. I'm using the .NET Framework Data provider for SQL Server. See images.

[Dataset Designer -> Configure / Edit Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVQoi.png)

[Error message after I click on Configure + Connection String](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1tv3.png)

It's important to note that the application connects using the same Connection String and everything worked fine previously.

SOLVED! Figured out the problem. The "Named Pipes" setting in the SQL configuration was disabled. First I tried to access the server via IP address and succeded. Then I checked under SQL Server Configuration Manager -> SQL Server Network Configuration -> Protocols for  -> Named Pipes and it was Disabled. I've set it to Enabled. I have no idea why it switched do Disabled, it was not like this before.

Comment: are you trying this on a different computer?

Comment: No, it is in the same environment as before - opening the same project .snl. The problem is, if I start (debug / release) the program, it connects fine (extracts data) but if I try to change a query on a table adapter, it displays this message. Dataset is using the same Connection String.

Comment: can you edit your question with your code of where it fails, flying blind here.

Comment: There is no code. It fails trough the Dataset designer when I try to edit a query on the Table Adapter. Probably some dll is missing but what puzzles me, it worked before and it still works if I connect trough the created application but not from the Visual Studio Dataset designer. Perhaps I could upload a screenshot!?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, yeah upload a screen shot of what you are looking at.

Comment: I've updated the question with images. Thanks!!